# K-Server Dynamic Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

I’m trying to get optimal solution for [K-server problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-server_problem) for 3 servers using dynamic algorithm.
The idea is to generate all possible permutation and check them all to find the optimum value.

I understand it’s a slow exhaust search algorithm with exponential time big O.
Anyway, this is what I have, as far as I understand it should work, but it gives me false value.

here first 3 points are the servers. And dist(x,y) function calculate Cartesian distance of the points x-th and y-th.

```
void optimalSol()
{

int cost[10][10][10][10];
for(int l=3; l<=totalPoints; l++)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=l; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=l; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<=l; k++)
            {
                int current_min=99999;
                //cost[i][j][k][l]=0;
                if((i!=l) && (j!=l) && (k!=l))
                    cost[i][j][k][l]=99999;
                else
                {

                    for(int m=0; m<=l; m++)
                    {
                        if(current_min > (cost[m][j][k][l-1] + dist(m, i)))
                        {
                            if(cost[m][j][k][l-1] + dist(m, i)>0)
                            current_min = cost[m][j][k][l-1] + dist(m, i);

                        }

                        else if(current_min > (cost[i][m][k][l-1] + dist(m,j)))
                        {
                            if(cost[i][m][k][l-1] + dist(m,j)>0)
                            current_min = cost[i][m][k][l-1] + dist(m,j);
                        }


                        else if(current_min > (cost[i][j][m][l-1] + dist(m,k)))
                        {
                            if(cost[i][j][m][l-1] + dist(m,k)>0)
                            current_min = cost[i][j][m][l-1] + dist(m,k);
                        }
                    }
                    cost[i][j][k][l] = current_min;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
  printCostTable(cost);
}
```